# Get NSData from buffer in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to get the image represented as buffer on this URL: http://apiapp-env2.elasticbeanstalk.com/?nomfile=FX1wTPcaZQ1456021964555.png

As you can see in the response, the image is a Buffer stored in the data object inside the JSON (I'm not the owner of the API, so I can't modify it)

Well, I'm trying to convert the image from the buffer to a UIImage.
This is what one of the things that I'have tried so far:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL, parameters: nil, encoding: .JSON)
  .validate()
  .response{
    request, response, json, error in
    if let _ = error{
      callback?(image: UIImage(named: "placeholder")!)
    }else if let _: AnyObject = json{
      do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json!, options:[])
        let bufferData = JSON(jsonObject)["Body"]["data"].array
        let imageData = NSData(bytes: bufferData!, length: bufferData!.count / sizeof(UInt32))
        let downloadImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
        callback?(image: downloadImage!)
      } catch {
        print("Error[performLoginSocialRequest]: \(error)")
      }
    }
}
```

But the downloadImage object is always nil.
Does anybody faced this issue before? If so, how can you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.array` on a `JSON` object from SwiftyJSON, it returns an array of type `[JSON]?`. While passing that into into the NSData init method appears to work, it is actually creating data by essentially cutting the `JSON` objects into one byte sizes and storing that data.

What you'll want to do is convert `bufferData` from the type `[JSON]` to `[UInt8]`.

```
let bufferData = JSON(jsonObject)["Body"]["data"].array
let bytes = bufferData!.flatMap { $0.uInt8 }
let imageData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes)
```

Comment: If that worked for you, please mark this answer as accepted to help anyone else who encounters a similar problem.